# react list + map component

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reactjs, google-maps-markers

I'm working in a react project and what I want to achieve is a list of items with a google map in the side. I've been working on it for a lot of time, looking for the best way to do it and I found many examples but they don't really have a good performance.
Also I want that when you over an item of the list the marker of the corresponding item in the map change the color or something like that, so I want to synchronize markers with the items in the list.

Here is my Map component to let you know what libraries I'm using for the moment:

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMaps from 'google-maps-api';
import MapConfig from 'config/maps.json';
import mapStyles from './map.styles';

const MapWithKey = GoogleMaps(MapConfig.API_KEY);

class Map extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const items = this.props.items;
        MapWithKey().then(( maps ) => {
            const map = new maps.Map(document.getElementById('js-map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false
            });

            for ( let item of items ) {
                new maps.Marker({
                    position: new maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude),
                    map: map
                });
            }
        });


        return(
            <div style={mapStyles} id="js-map">{this.props.children}</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

I notice during the development I cannot add the markers in the state because every time I would add one, the component will rerender again.

Do you know a good way to do so and structure the components in a good way?
Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate).

This lifecycle method allows you to decide whether the component should be re-rendered each time the state or props are updated.

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
  return false;
}
```

Now you're safe to store your markers in `this.state` and update them using the imperative Maps API, without worrying about your component trying to re-render.

It's also worth mentioning that `shouldComponentUpdate` won't affect the initial render and you can still force updates past it using [`forceUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate).

You might also want to consider restructuring your component to follow some best practices. You can use the `ref` prop with a callback to get a reference to the DOM element without needing an `id`.

```
return(
  <div style={mapStyles} ref={containerMounted}>{this.props.children}</div>
);
```

Then you can move your initialisation logic into the new `containerMounted` method.

```
containerMounted(container) {
  MapWithKey().then(( maps ) => {
    const map = new maps.Map(container, {
      // ...
    });

    // save a reference to map for later
    this.setState({ map });
  });
}
```

Finally, it's important that your markers re-render when the props change. Previously we could have done this inside the `render` function. Part of the reason why you're seeing bad performance is because you were creating new markers each time render was called. Instead you need to move the existing ones.

```
// create the markers before initial render
componentWillMount() {
  this.createMarkers(this.props.items);
}

// recreate the markers only when props changes
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.items === this.props.items) return;
  this.removeMarkers(this.state.markers);
  this.createMarkers(nextProps.items);
}

// remove a list of markers from the map
removeMarkers(markers) {
  markers.forEach(m => m.setMap(null));
}

// create a list of markers on the current map
createMarkers(items) {
  const markers = items.map(item => {
    return new maps.Marker({
      position: new maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude),
      map: this.state.map
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You're amazing!!! Such a good answer, just one thing... in componentWillReceiveProps you're using this.state.markers without setting it before, I guess it's in createMarkers where you create a markers collection, correct?

Comment: and another thing, maps object, the one that returns the promise from GMaps is only accessible in containerMounted, I tried to set it in the state or a property of the class but as it's a promise, it's not available when needed

Comment: Yeah, you might need to have a `getInitialState` method that returns the initial version of the markers. Yeah, if you want to use `maps` as well as the `map` object, you'll need to expose it in the same way.

Comment: I tried to expose it to the state, but as it's a promise, it comes after the first render, so it's undefined :(

Comment: Expose the promise on the component too, then you can create multiple listeners for it.

Comment: I'll try :) Thx! BTW really appreciate your help, amazing!